# Is it possible to proof an div element of visibility inside a "overflow-x:scroll" div-container ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently trying to figure out how to get the information of how much percent is visbile of a div inside a overflow-x:scroll container. I also need to know if it comes from the right or from the left ? Is this possible somehow ?

Comment: I don't think there is any mechanism in css or jquery. You will have to apply your own mathematics. You can find out height like this - `parent container height - content height`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be helpfull. You could edit the code from the answer to that question to check if the element was scrolled in from the right or the left.

[Check if element is visible after scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/jquery-check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling)

To calculate the percentage visable you just need to compare child's size to the parent's size and what the 'left' offset of the child is.

(I might add a code example later)

**EDIT**

I made a small example that show how you can detect the visible percentage of that child inside an "overflow-x:scroll" div-container **and** if the child comes from left or right.

```
<style>
#parent {
    overflow-x:scroll;
    width: 300px;
    height:120px;
    border: solid 1px #000;
}
#child {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background:#FF0;
    margin-left: 200px;
}
#scrollPane {
    width: 800px;
}
</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        alert(percantageVisible() + "% of the child is visible");
    });
});

function percantageVisible()
{
    var parent = $("#parent");
    var parentLeftOffset = parent.offset().left;
    var parentRightOffset = parentLeftOffset + parent.width();

    var child = $("#child");
    var childLeftOffset = child.offset().left;
    var childRightOffset = childLeftOffset + child.width();

    if(childLeftOffset < parentLeftOffset && childRightOffset > parentLeftOffset && childRightOffset < parentRightOffset){
        // percentage from the left
        var width = child.width();
        var hiddenWidth = Math.abs(childLeftOffset - parentLeftOffset);
        var visibleWidth = width - hiddenWidth;
        return visibleWidth/(width/100);
    } 
    else if(childRightOffset > parentRightOffset && childLeftOffset < parentRightOffset && childLeftOffset > parentLeftOffset ){
        // percentage from the right
        var width = child.width();
        var hiddenWidth = Math.abs(parentRightOffset -childRightOffset);
        var visibleWidth = width - hiddenWidth;
        return visibleWidth/(width/100);
    }
    else if (childLeftOffset > parentLeftOffset && childRightOffset < parentRightOffset){
        // all visible
        return 100;
    }
    else{
        // invisible
        return 0;
    }
}
</script>

<div id="parent">
    <div id="scrollPane">
        <div id="child"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
<button id="button">check percentage</button>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @SebastianBoldt if you wouldn't mind checking the question as answered ;)